# Angular 6 i18n localize FormField Input default value

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, angular6

In my Angular 6 app I want to prefill an input field with an internationalized default value (using the new Angular 6 internationalization feature).

Using `i18n-value="inputFieldDefaultValueForTeamName"` together with `value="###{{displayName}}'s Team###"`does not work and leaves the value blank.
It does work for the placeholder though.

My setup is the following:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onCreateTeam(f)" #f="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="teamName" i18n="teamNameLabel">###TeamName###</label>
    <input type="text" id="teamName" name="teamName" 
         i18n-placeholder="inputfieldPlaceholderForTeamName"
         placeholder="###{{displayName}}'s Team###"

         i18n-value="inputFieldDefaultValueForTeamName"
         value="###{{displayName}}'s Team###"

         ngModel
         minlength="2" maxlength="100" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" i18n="createTeamButton">###Create Team###</button>

</form>
```

And in my component:

```
onCreateTeam(form: NgForm) {   
    //    ...
    const teamName = form.value.teamName;
    //    ...
}
```

Is there any way to set the internationalized default value of the input field?

Many thanks in advance!

Kind regards

Setup

Answer (score 0):

Okay so now I achieved it by changing the input field in the following way:

```
 <input type="text" id="teamName" name="teamName"
         i18n-placeholder="inputfieldPlaceholderForTeamName"
         placeholder="###{{displayName}}'s Team###"
         #teamNameInput
         [(ngModel)]="teamName"
         minlength="2" maxlength="100" required>
```

And then in the Code:

```
teamName = '';
//If you have an ngIf wrapper, the setter will be called with undefined, and then 
again with a reference once ngIf allows it to render.
@ViewChild('teamNameInput') set defaultTeamName(input: ElementRef) {
  if (!!input) {
    // needs to be wrapped in a 0 timeout to prevent ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (following https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild Line 23)
    setTimeout(() => {
      //set the localized placeholder as the input fields value
      this.teamName = input.nativeElement.placeholder;
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

Feels like a hack but I guess that's the only way to access localized values directly in the code for now, until Angular v7 is released.